# Area of a triangle geometry

Tags: geometry

Is there an easy way to solve the following problem?  Thank you very much!

> A triangle with sides 6, 8, and 10 has its shortest side doubled in length while the other two sides remain the same. What is the area of the new triangle?

Comment: Heron's formula

Comment: @1110101001 You should make an answer out of this comment.

Comment: Thanks. I found trigonometric proof of the formula at this link -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If the shortest side is doubled while the other two remain the same, the new side lengths are 12, 8, 10.

Then use Heron's formula to compute the area given the side lengths.